# Meaning of "smooth partition"

Tags: set-partition

In the paper *Edge analysis and identification using the continous shearlet transform* (by K. Guo, D. Labate and W. Lim) I encountered the term *smooth partition* of a set. I do not understand the term *smooth partition* Lets be precise what is written:

> [...]let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $R^2$ and assume a smooth partition $\Omega=\cup_n(\Omega_n \cup \Gamma)$, where [...]

now there are severel requirements listed. To be clear, I know what a partition is, but I only know the term *smooth* in the sense of a *smooth function*.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: I think the "smooth" is used here because the partition is defined such that each boundary is generated by the $C^3$ curve. In many cases, a sufficient regular boundary is needed in the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this makes sense. I do not see a "deeper" meaning neither.